# Quantifying a free variable in an example from "How To Prove It" by Velleman

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is an example from *How To Prove It* by Daniel J. Velleman (2nd Ed., p. 71):

> Example 2.2.3. Analyze the logical forms of the following statements.
>
> 1. Statements about the natural numbers. The universe of discourse is $\mathbb N$.
>
>    a. $x$ is a perfect square.

And here is the solution:

> 1. a. This means that $x$ is the square of some natural number, or in other words $\exists y(x = y^2)$.

My question is regarding the free variable $x$. Is it correct to leave it free, as the author has done? I was under the impression that, by convention, a free variable may be assumed to be universally quantified, which I think wouldn't make sense in this case.

If I wanted to fully formalize the statement, how would I do that? My best guess is as follows:

$$\exists x\exists y(x = y^2)$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't confuse variables (the only ones that can be quantified) with individual constants.

The logical form of the sentence "$x$ is a perfect square" is indeed $\exists y (x = y^2)$. In this formula, $x$ plays the role of an individual constant, not of a variable, because it refers to one specific individual in the universe of discourse $\mathbb{N}$.

The meaning of $\exists x \exists y (x = y^2)$ is "there is a perfect square", which is completely different because it does not refer to one specific individual in the universe of discourse $\mathbb{N}$.

---

*Remark.* The starting point of my answer above is the fact that the exercise claims that "$x$ is a perfect square" is a [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(logic)), that is a a meaningful declarative sentence that is true or false because every sign in it is interpreted, hence $x$ should refer to a specific individual in the universe of discourse.

If you see "$x$ is a perfect square" just as a phrase which is not a sentence (and so it is not true or false because not all its signs are interpreted), then you can see $x$ as a free variable (waiting for an interpretation to assign a truth value to the phrase). Even in this case the logical (but meaningless) form of the phrase is $\exists y (x = y^2)$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy way to distinguish between individual constants and free variables? Or do I need to figure it out from context?

Comment: @Calculemus - In a formal language, variables and individual constants belong to two disjoint sets, so it is immediate to distinguish each other (but in this setting a formula is meaningless without a formal interpretation). In an informal setting, such as the one in your exercise, you need to figure it out from the context.

Comment: Thanks again :)

Comment: I don't quite agree with this answer. The English language sentence "$x$ is a perfect square" and the mathematical notation sentence "$\exists y(x=y^2)$" can be regarded as equivalent sentences with $x$ as a free variable in *each* of those sentences.

Comment: Also, regarding the OP's statement that "a free variable may be assumed to be universally quantified", that's not always true. Open mathematical sentences, meaning mathematical sentences with unquantified free variables, are very common and useful things. For one, they can be used to define sets. For example, the subset $[0,\infty)$ is the solution set of the open sentence "$x$ is a perfect square" when variables are restricted to the real numbers.

Comment: @LeeMosher - A formula is meaningless if there are free variables that are not interpreted. "Meaningless" means that you cannot assign a truth value.

Comment: I agree that you cannot assign a truth value. I would shy away from using that to conclude that the formula is "meaningless"; that seems to invites the corollary that sentences with open variables are "useless", which is far from the case.

Comment: @LeeMosher -  I never said that open formulas are useless, just that they are "meaningless". The set $[0, +\infty)$ is the extension of the set $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists y (x = y^2)\}$, but it corresponds to (i.e. it is defined by) a _closed_ formula in the first-order language of set theory: $\forall x (x \in X \iff x \in \mathbb{R} \land \exists y (x = y^2)$.

Comment: That sentence is not a closed formula, it contains the free variable $X$.

Comment: @LeeMosher - You should put an existential quantifier $\exists X$ in front of my formula. What I mean is just an particular instance of the [axiom of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification). Note that such a set $X$ is unique by extensionality.

Comment: Even though formulas with free variables don't have truth values until you specify values for the free variables, they do have meanings. The meaning of a formula with $n$ free variables is a certain $n$-place relation, namely the set of those $n$-tuples of values that, if assigned to the free variables, would make the formula true.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - I totally agree with you, except that I identify the meaning of a formula with its truth value, so I cannot say that an open formula is "meaningful" (in this specific and technical sense of "meaning"). I would rather say that an open formula is "sensical" or "sensible" (sorry, I'm not a native English speaker). From my point of view, we are saying the same thing, it is just a terminological (or, if you prefer, a philosophical) matter.